# Regex combination of 2 urls: difference 1 word in between

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have 2 regex expressions that I need to combine into one. I'm looking for 1 regex that will validate both URLs below.

**1st**

URL: `cart/auto/done/?tx=99445068UN007545N&st=Completed&amt=297.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=`

Regex: `cart\/\w+\/done.*`

**2nd**

URL: `/cart/done/?tx=5CW532565J668892C&st=Completed&amt=249.01&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=`

Regex: `cart\/done.*`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure you can do that like `cart/(\w+/)?done.*` in GA. Please try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Alternations. This should work.

```
\/?(cart\/done|cart\/\w+\/done).*
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uO0pS6/2)

For more information on alternations see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)